# Add interakting slider in header file of magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

The Block Code is as follows:

```
{{block type="interaktingslider/interaktingslider" name="interaktingslider"}}
```

can anybody give a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the block code in a static block and include the static block in the xml.
After you need to design it.